# How can I test if there is collinearity between Independent variables in LMER models?

Tags: r, lme4

I want to test the collinearity of my predictors in the following logit model:

```
m4 <- glmer(prime ~ EnglishTestGrade*test+(1+test|Subject)+ (1|items),family=binomial(link 
"logit"), data = dataset, control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=2000000)))
 summary(m4)
```

"EnglishTestGrade" is continuous predictor (centered), "test" is categorical with two levels (I applied deviation contrasts) and items are categorical with 20 levels.

How can I test if there is collinearity between Independent variables in this model?

warning:

Error in vif.default(m4) : model contains fewer than 2 terms
In addition: Warning message:
In vif.default(m4) : No intercept: vifs may not be sensible.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possibly useful answer by searching the R SIG for mixed models:

https://markmail.org/search/?q=+list%3Aorg.r-project.r-sig-mixed-models+variance+inflation+factor#query:%20list%3Aorg.r-project.r-sig-mixed-models%20variance%20inflation%20factor+page:1+mid:cskyemxrfh73nyyx+state:results

It's an answer by John Fox, so should be credible:

> For a linear model, it's also possible to calculate VIFs (and generalized
> VIFs) from the covariance matrix of the coefficients, and this approach
> probably generalizes more readily. This is also the approach taken in the
> vif() function in the car package, for which there's just an "lm" method.

> E.g., for a model fit by lmer() or glmer() in the lme4 package, the
> following should work:

```
coef.merMod <- function(object, ...){
    fixef(object)
}
vcov.merMod <- function (object, ...){
    as.matrix(lme4:::vcov.merMod(object))
}


vif.merMod <- function(mod, ...){
    car:::vif.lm(mod, ...)
}
```

> The first two functions are necessary because car:::vif.lm() expects coef()
> to return the fixed-effect vector and vcov() to return an ordinary matrix.

> I hope this helps,
> John

Answer (score 1):

`library(performance)` is an excellent package and should have all you need.

Within that there is a function `check_model()` that runs many, if not all, the tests you would need on generalised linear mixed effects models (and many others). One of the output graphs measures the amount of co-linearity.

https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/check_model.html

Answer (score 1):

As @MrSwaggins [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74396436/9096420), there are other checks this package provides as well, but all you are asking for is `check_collinearity()`

```
library(performance)
check_collinearity(m4)
```